# How to copy PivotTable values without copying it?

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

I have a sheet with a Pivot Table, I want to copy whole PT as values to another worksheet. How can I do that without using `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` methods?

I am wondering about something like:

```
wsTarget.Cells = wsPivot.Cells.Value
```

But it's giving me an **`Out of memory`** error.

Comment: Look at the help for the PivotTable object, then you can get the objects contained within and reference them.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837611.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one of the ways to copy(/tranfsfer) PivotTable without actually copying it is:

```
wsTarget.Range(wsp.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address).Value = _ 
  wsPivot.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
```